# UIButtons & UILabels inside a tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have two UIButtons and some labels inside a table view cell. I have 2 sections, the first section contains one table view cell and inside of that cell there are two UIButtons that call on an api to fetch new data for the cells in section 2. In a certain if case, a label is created because the string is very long so I have to create a new frame for the cell.

The problem that I am currently having is that the button text also gets update with new information and sometimes the string is short or sometimes the string is long, so I have to remove the button and a add a new button with a new frame to fit the new string. But if the past button string was shorter than the new one, the button still appears in the background. I tried removing it from the superview and also checking that it has removed from the superview (check that it is null once I remove it) and it is, but it still appears on the screen. The same thing happens with the UILabels as well. I also tried to removing them from super view with a tag (viewWithTag:123). Anyone have any pointers, ideas, suggestions, anything really, that could help me figure/fix this out?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.1];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;

        if(cell==nil) { NSLog(@"Cell is still nil");}
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = nil;
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {

            dosageButton                            = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            amountButton                            = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

            [dosageButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
            [dosageButton setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 0)];
            [amountButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
            [amountButton setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15.5, 0, 0)];


            if(strengths.count == 0) { [dosageButton setTitle:@"Dosage" forState:UIControlStateNormal];}
            else
            {

                [dosageButton setTitle:selectedStrength forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                CGSize stringsize = [selectedStrength sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
                [dosageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 27.5, stringsize.width + 30, 30)];
            }

            if(quantity.count == 0) { [amountButton setTitle:@"Amount" forState:UIControlStateNormal];}
            else
            {

                int value = [selectedQuantity intValue];
                if (value == 1)
                {
                    NSString *amountAndFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", selectedQuantity, selectedFormat];
                    [amountButton setTitle:amountAndFormat forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    CGSize stringsize = [selectedStrength sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
                    CGSize amountSize = [amountAndFormat sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];

                    if(amountSize.width+stringsize.width > 250)
                    {
                        dosageButton.frame                      = CGRectMake(5, 27.5, 130, 30);
                        amountButton.frame                      = CGRectMake(140, 27.5, 160, 30);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [amountButton setFrame:CGRectMake(stringsize.width + 40, 27.5, amountSize.width + (amountSize.height * 2.1), 30)];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    NSString *amountAndFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", selectedQuantity, selectedFormatPlural];
                    [amountButton setTitle:amountAndFormat forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    CGSize stringsize = [selectedStrength sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
                    CGSize amountSize = [amountAndFormat sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
                    if(amountSize.width + stringsize.width> 250)
                    {
                        dosageButton.frame                      = CGRectMake(5, 27.5, 130, 30);
                        amountButton.frame                      = CGRectMake(140, 27.5, 160, 30);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [amountButton setFrame:CGRectMake(stringsize.width + 40, 27.5, amountSize.width + (amountSize.height * 2.1), 30)];
                    }
                }

            }

            [dosageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDosages:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [amountButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showAmount:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            //[cell.contentView addSubview:dosageButton];
            //[cell.contentView addSubview:amountButton];
            //adding it to view instead of cell because of userInteraction.
            //if I add it to cell.contentView and userInteractionEnabled = NO
            //then the user can't press the button
            //but if the it is enabled then they can click the cell and looks tacky!

            [self.view addSubview:dosageButton];
            [self.view addSubview:amountButton];
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 1)
        {
            if(localName.count == 0)
            {
                //Nothing
            }

            else
            {
            CGRect longStringFrame = CGRectMake(12, 4, 250, 120);
            //UILabel *longStringLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:longStringFrame];
            UILabel *longStringLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:longStringFrame];
            longStringLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            longStringLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            longStringLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Something super duper long. Some really really long string that has a lot of information and cannot fit in one line so I have to use numberOfLines = 0 and NSLineBreakByWordWrapping. This string is really really really long.]];
            longStringLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            longStringLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            longStringLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            cell.textLabel.text = @"";
            longStringLabel.tag = 123;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:longStringLabel];
            }
        }


}



- (void) showDosages:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [dosageButton removeFromSuperview];
    [amountButton removeFromSuperview];
    [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:123] removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dosageButton superview]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[amountButton superview]);


    //Also tried it this way as well. Didn't work
    //[dosageButton performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    //[amountButton performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    dispatch_async(someDispatch, ^{ NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://somewebsite.com"]]]; [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES]; });
}
```

showAmount is similar to showDosages

Comment: pls add your code for reference.....

Comment: plz put your code along with images of your tableview

Comment: @NANNAV edited OP and added code

Comment: @Unheilig the problem is that I am using the same button over again. I edited the post and added code.

Comment: When you recycle a cell, any modifications you made to the old one will still be there, including any buttons you added.  You need to tag the buttons and then use viewWithTag to find the button the next time around.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a custom cell put all the labels & buttons you want, give an iboutles so that you can easily manage things.

Custom cell tutorial
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/

Once you made your cell you can set the height of cell according to your string. Your buttons will automatically adjusted when your cell size is increased or decreased

Comment: The problem with this is that I am using the cells to display cell.textLabel.text as well as label.texts as well. And wouldn't this create buttons on every cell? I have worked with custom cells before but never did I put buttons inside so I don't know if each cell would create a button because of `if(cell == nil) { //create custom cells here }`

Comment: @Chris - You're already putting buttons inside all the cells.  When you recycle a cell whatever buttons were previously in it will still be there.  If you only want buttons in some cells use the cell identifier feature to divide them into two classes.

Comment: @HotLicks I am? How so? I thought I was only adding it to the first section, ie section ==1, and creating it in there. How would I divide them into two classes?

Comment: When the cells roll off the end of the screen they go into a pool, based on the "reuseIdentifier" value.  You only specify one identifier, therefore only one pool.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example of multiple cell identifier hope it might help

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

if(flag == 0) {

   MainArticleTableViewCell *cell = (MainArticleTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[MainArticleTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
   }

   cell.textLabel.text= @"Cell1";

   return cell;
}
else {
   NewsTableViewCell *cell = (NewsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[NewsTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 orientation:currentOrientation] autorelease];

   }

   cell.textLabel.text= @"Cell1";

   return cell;
}

return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using this along with custom cells and creating the buttons inside the cell and then returning them.